# What is the best place to post job listings for EE devs?

Tags: templates, javascript, css, html

I just want to find some talented people to work with that are already familiar with the platform.

Comment: This is a question better posed on Twitter via the #eecms hashtag.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend posting on [Director-EE](http://director-ee.com/), then tweeting about it using the [#eecms](http://goo.gl/JfmImq) hashtag. That'll get you the most exposure.

(Shameless plug: I'm available for EE work, [get in touch](http://www.kristengrote.com/contact))